# SSRS 2008 Reports not compatible with IE 11

Tags: .net-3.5, ssrs-2008, internet-explorer-11

We have SSRS Reports built in 2008 version. Till now our Client's Machine browser version was IE 9 so we didn't faced any Compatibility issue. But now all client machine's browsers are getting upgraded to IE 11 and upon testing the SSRS reports in IE 11, few reports are not compatible with IE 11. Reports are displaying at Top left corner of the browser leaving all the other places as blank. But this issue was not applicable for all the reports. I am wondering why it is been a issue for only 3 reports and others are working fine.

One more Interesting thing is, In development URL, all the Reports are working fine in IE 11 and above issue is happening in Test and Production environment. but We have deployed the same code in all 3 environment.

So I really looking for some help here to understand and arrive to a solution so that all our reports works fine in IE 11.

Thank you.
Sharath

Answer (score 0):

It has a lot of compatibility issues in IE 11. Currently the most effective workaround is Press F12 button in IE, in Emulation tab, change the document mode into 9.